# jQuery Show/Hide - CSS display values are affecting my layout

Tags: jquery, css, show-hide

jQuery uses the CSS `display` property under the hood of the simple `show()` and `hide()` functions. The following HTML includes three buttons, each wrapped in a `<span>` tag, and all three `<span>` tags are placed in a parent `<div>` container. On page load, the `<span>` tags are hidden using jQuery `hide()`, and, at some point later on, they are displayed using the `show()` function. The HTML is now in the following state with the `<span>` tag having received the style value `display: block;`.

```html
<div style="text-align:right; width:100%;">
    <span style="display:block">
        <input type="button" value="Button1" />
    </span>
    <span style="display:block">
        <input type="button" value="Button2" />
    </span>
    <span style="display:block">
        <input type="button" value="Button3" />
    </span>
</div>
```

In Firefox (3.5) the span elements appear stacked vertically on top of each other, whereas in IE they appear inline. I would have expected the latter in both browsers because I thought that the default layout for span tags was inline.

If I manually change the style from `display:block` to `display: inline;`, it looks correct in Firefox. Essentially, when showing an element, jQuery is using a value for `display` that is not always valid. Adding `display: block`; is enough to show the element, but not enough to show it with the inline layout I require.

So, to my questions:

1. Is this a known issue with jQuery? I am using jQuery 1.2.6.
2. Has anyone experienced this problem before, and how did you get around it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At first it seemed from the responses that using the show/hide functions would not be possible if I wanted a value of `display` other than `block`.

However, I then noticed that, when the `<span>` tags were in the hidden state, jQuery had added an attribute called `oldBlock` to each of them. I then realized that this was for temporary storage of the `display` CSS value when the element is hidden, so that the appropriate value can be reinstated when the elements are shown again.

All I therefore have to do is set the appropriate value for display before I hide the elements.

Initial state:

```html
<div style="text-align:right; width:100%;">
    <span style="display:inline">
        <input type="button" value="Button1" />
    </span>
    ...
</div>
```

Calling `.hide()` takes us to this state:

```
<div style="text-align:right; width:100%;">
    <span style="display:none" oldBlock="inline">
        <input type="button" value="Button1" />
    </span>
    ...
</div>
```

Calling `show()` brings us back to this state:

```
<div style="text-align:right; width:100%;">
    <span style="display:inline">
        <input type="button" value="Button1" />
    </span>
    ...
</div>
```

The main problem was that I was NOT giving the `<span>` elements a value for `display` in my initial state. They would therefore implicitly receive the browser default, which appears to be `inline` as I expected. However, jQuery will only use the `oldBlock` attribute if you explicitly set the value for `display` *before* you call the `hide()` function. If there is no `oldBlock` attribute, the `show()` function uses the default value of `block`.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using show/hide use addClass/removeClass and have the style you wish to be applied set up using the class.

```
.hidden
{
    display: none;
}

.inline
{
    display: inline;
}

.block
{
    display: block;
}
```

Sample usage:

```
$('.menuitem').hover(
      function() {
           $(this).parent()
                  .find('span')
                  .removeClass('inline block')
                  .addClass('hidden');
           $(this).addClass('inline');
      },
      function() {
           $(this).addClass('inline');
      }
});
```

Comment: It does seem that if I want the level of control such that I can choose the value of the Display style property, I will not be able to use the show/hide functions. This is a shame but to be expected. Thanks for this suggestion.

Comment: the problem with this approach is it is basically a hack. your code knowing too much about your css. yes it can definitely work sometimes but i'm trying to avoid this as much as possible

Answer (score 3):

I haven't had this problem, but if you need to, you can explicitly set css properties like this:

```
$(this).show('fast').css("display","inline");
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't had this specific problem, but for more control use .toggleClass()

Comment: This would be a great solution to replace toggle(), but a more direct replacement for show/hide would be add/remove as the semantics are directly equivalent.

Comment: This is fine, but show() and hide() involve some animation, and are interchangeable with stuff like slideDown and slideUp, so if he wants to keep the animation, just changing the class wouldn't do that.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is possible at all to animate inline elements.